# Split a DataFrame column value on '|' and get all items except first

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to split a column value on '|' , get all items except first item for a new column 'address'.
Whats it makes more complicates is that the number of items is not always the same!

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["Luc  Krier|2363  Ryan Road"],
  ["Jeanny  Thorn|2263 Patton Lane|Raleigh North Carolina"],
  ["Teddy E Beecher|2839 Hartland Avenue|Fond Du Lac Wisconsin|US"],
  ["Philippe  Schauss|1 Im Oberdor|Allemagne"],
 ["Meindert I Tholen|Hagedoornweg 138|Amsterdam|NL"]
]).toDF("s")
```

I've tried this already:

split, size substring but can't get it done. Any help much appreciated !

Expected output:

```
addres
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
2363  Ryan Road"
2263 Patton Lane|Raleigh North Carolina"
2839 Hartland Avenue|Fond Du Lac Wisconsin|US"
1 Im Oberdor|Allemagne"
Hagedoornweg 138|Amsterdam|NL"
```

Comment: So only for first row you dont want the first split?

Comment: I want to split the values from column `s` on '|' and the new column `address` only contains all items, ***except the first item*** after the split. (number of items is not always the same !!)  - Edited my question and output sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
df1.select(concat_ws('|',slice(split('s','\|'),2,1000))).show()

+------------------------------------------+
|concat_ws(|, slice(split(s, \|), 2, 1000))|
+------------------------------------------+
|2363  Ryan Road|Long Lake South Dakota    |
|2263 Patton Lane|Raleigh North Carolina   |
|2839 Hartland Avenue|Fond Du Lac Wisconsin|
|1 Im Oberdor|Allemagne                    |
|Hagedoornweg 138|Amsterdam                |
+------------------------------------------+
```

where 1000 is the max_length of your array, given an arbitrary large int for now.

Comment: It's giving me an error. I tried `df1=df1.withColumn('address', df1.select(concat_ws('|',slice(split('s','\|'),2,1000))))`
`invaled argument, not a string or column: slice(Column<b'split(s, \\| '>,2,1000)... use lit array, struct or create map function`

Comment: you are using select with withColumn...use this df1=df1.withColumn('address', concat_ws('|',slice(split('s','\|'),2,1000)))

Comment: have you imported from pyspark.sql.functions import split,slice,concat_ws...it's working as expected for me

Comment: Still same error `TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: slice(Column<b'split(s,\\|)'>,2,1000) of type <class 'slice'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array, 'struct, or 'create map'function.`

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`. Then i use: `df1=df1.withColumn('address', F.concat_ws('|',slice(F.split('s','\|'),2,1000)))`. I got it. Forgot the` F.slice`. BTW strange warning

Comment: You ignored F.slice

Comment: That's because it is using python's slice method instead of pyspark

Answer (score 2):

Function 'instr' can be used for find first '|', and 'substring' for getting result:

```
df1.selectExpr(
  "substring(s, instr(s,'|') + 1, length(s))"
)
```

Or regexpr from string start to first '|':

```
df1.select(
  regexp_replace($"s", "^[^\\|]+\\|", "")
)
```